# How to remove/identify a certain Eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to identify/hide this toolbar from Eclipse?

[image: toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this:

> Windows -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Bar and uncheck Enable the Launch Bar

in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024473/cant-remove-new-elements-in-eclipse-toolbar